# How can I find the individual components of a tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset file?

Tags: tensorflow

suppose you have a file created by the tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset? How can I access the individual components? Specifically I want to max value of every batchdataset.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211655/python-data-ops-dataset-ops-batchdataset-how-to-use-it-to-create-training-and

Comment: Thanks. that is very helpful